# Multiple conditions on TFS field

Tags: tfs

I need to set a TFS field as required based on two conditions. For example i want to set the field state as required if

1. Field "IsValid" value is not true
2. Field "Test Type" value is "Analysis"

Is it possible to set multiple conditions in TFS?

Answer (score 3):

Even if it sounds too late, here's a tip that worked for me. It's a little tedious so I'll try to be clear.

Here is my context :
First I'm working with TFS 2018 RTM (16.122.27102.1) but i don't think it's important in that case.

- I added a new field : an "end user description" on User Stories or BUGs to generate a change log based on a simple query.
- I wanted this HTML Field to be mandatory only when

  - the Work Item is "Closed"
  - the reason is "Work finished"
  - the activity is "Development"
  - a new boolean field "Ignore for change log" is not True

Workaround :
I created a new field : "Custom.EndUserDescriptionMandatory" (Integer).
The order is important.
The idea is that when a Field that plays on the condition is changed, that new field is set to 1.
After that when the value does not respond to the required condition, that new field is set to 0.
Here is the XML for the rules :

```xml
<FIELD name="Mandatory user description" refname="Custom.EndUserDescriptionMandatory" type="Integer">
    <DEFAULT from="value" value="0" />
    <WHENCHANGED field="Custom.ChangeLogIgnore">
        <COPY from="value" value="1" />
    </WHENCHANGED>
    <WHENCHANGED field="Custom.EndUserDescription">
        <COPY from="value" value="1" />
    </WHENCHANGED>
    <WHENCHANGED field="System.Reason">
        <COPY from="value" value="1" />
    </WHENCHANGED>
    <WHENCHANGED field="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity">
        <COPY from="value" value="1" />
    </WHENCHANGED>
    <WHENCHANGED field="System.State">
        <COPY from="value" value="1" />
    </WHENCHANGED>
    <WHENNOT value="Closed" field="System.State">
        <COPY from="value" value="0" />
    </WHENNOT>
    <WHENNOT value="Work finished" field="System.Reason">
        <COPY from="value" value="0" />
    </WHENNOT>
    <WHEN value="true" field="Custom.ChangeLogIgnore">
        <COPY from="value" value="0" />
    </WHEN>
    <WHENNOT value="" field="Custom.EndUserDescription">
        <COPY from="value" value="0" />
    </WHENNOT>
    <WHENNOT value="Development" field="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity">
        <COPY from="value" value="0" />
    </WHENNOT>
    <HELPTEXT>(Internal use) allows to know whether Custom.EndUserDescription is mandatory or not</HELPTEXT>
</FIELD>
```

Finally I added a rule to the Workflow :

```xml
<STATE value="Closed">
    <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Custom.EndUserDescription">
            <WHENNOT value="0" field="Custom.EndUserDescriptionMandatory">
                <REQUIRED />
            </WHENNOT>
        </FIELD>
    </FIELDS>
</STATE>
```

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms: It's not supported now.

Here has been a featured request in Voice of VS. You can also vote for it.

> **Allow nested when, whennot, whenchanged, and whennotchanged in TFS
> work item definitions**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5760933-allow-nested-when-whennot-whenchanged-and-whenn